# como instalar o java JDK e JRE no windows 10?

Tags: java

Olá;

Estou fazendo o curso de desenvolvimento Android. Estou na:

Seção - 2 - Instalação e configuração no windows

Aula - 5 - Instalação Java, JDK e JRE

PROBLEMA - Não estou conseguindo realizar a configuração da variável de ambiente.

*** A variável de sistema JAVA_HOME, aparentemente está correta (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151);

*** A variável de sistema PATH, não estou conseguindo configurar corretamente:

Caminho sem edição (C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath);

Caminho com edição (C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%\bin);

Mesmo após a edição ao buscas CMD-JAVAC, não consegui configurar as variáveis de ambiente corretamente.

Por gentileza gostaria de solictar um suporte;

Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não sei vou olhar mais tarde está em casa no meu notebook ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No Windows 10 Home**, quando clicar editar o path, há uma janela que abre. Nesta janela clicar no botão "Editar Texto" e não Edit.

Ir no final da linha e adicionar `;&JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Dar OK e pronto!

Comment: obrigado consegui

Answer (score 1):

Edite o item `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%\bin` e deixe-o apenas como `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`.

Crie uma variável de ambiente chamada `JAVA_HOME` com o valor `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`.

Answer (score 0):

Verificou se não tem outra versão do JAVA já instalado? Pode ocorrer conflito de versões, sugiro remover um das versões e realizar a configuração! As versões novas do jdk não possuem o pacote jre, logo você pode apontar`JRE_HOME` para o `JAVA_HOME`, ou não declarar essa variável de ambiente.

Comment: obrigado já foi resolvido